# How to update CollectionView's numberOfItemsInSection after block finishes executing

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, objective-c-blocks

I would like to put up a `UICollectionView` of pictures downloaded from a backend provider, and am running the issue where every time my collection view controller is initialized, the required method

```
- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

always returns 0, despite my providing the code `[self.profilePicturesStorage count]`. I understand that because I am using a block to populate the `self.profilePicturesStorage` property, at the view initialization it will always return 0 (since the block hasn't finished executing) My question is, how do I update CollectionView's `numberOfItemsInSection:` method *after* my block has finished downloading all the pictures?

This is the block that I execute in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            if ([objects count] > 0){
                //... Skip additional code that parse out the downloaded objects
                [self.profilePicturesStorage addObject:userPicture];
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"There aren't any pictures for the current user");
            }
        }
    }];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make sure that self.profilePicturesStorage is not nil? If it is that would lead to your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[collectionView reloadData]` should be all you need.